# Behavior for simulating data dependancy on combobox selection/datagrid row selection

Tags: wpf, expression-blend, sketchflow

I have a Sketchflow project setup already that is using generated dummy data for a combobox and a datagrid.  What I would like to do is simulate dependant behavior such that the datagrid is populated WHEN a selection is made in the combobox.  For example, the combobox has a list of clients.  When a client is selected, their respective files should be displayed in the datagrid.

Also, next to the grid, there are some textblocks that corrrespond to details about the selected file.  (File size, etc.)  When a file is selected in the datagrid (basically a row selection), the details should populate dynamically.  (ex. "File Size: 500").

I realize these could be 2 different questions but they seem like the same principle would apply in both cases.  The idea is that given some selected value, dummy data should populate some OTHER related control.  My research leads me to believe it will be a behavior but I cannot find a tutorial on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Do a Master-Details binding.  Start with a listbox and a canvas and try this: 
1.Create a single, sample data source
2.Click on the 'list' mode button above the data source (in the 'data' tab)
3.Drag field(s) onto a list view for the list selection
4.Click the 'details' mode button above the data source (in the 'data' tab)
5.Drag the other field(s) onto the area where you want to display the details

You should be able to work out a similar approach with your combobox as master and grid as detail and then you may be able to take the same master-details approach with grid-textblock if you add file info to the same, original dataset